# How do I set destination permissions with rsync (chown chmod)

Tags: linux, rsync, fedora

I am trying to do a local rsync, from a mount point to a local folder. I need to set the owner, group, and permissions to specific settings. Here is what I am using:

```
 rsync -rtlv --chown=process:sambausers --chmod=D770,F770 /mnt/owncloud_mnt/Engineering/ /Drive_D/docs/Engineering_test
```

I end up with permissions 760 on both directories and files, and root:root on ownership (rsync is run as root).

What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Is the target filesystem something like NTFS, since it's "Drive_D"?

Comment: target filesystem is ext4

Comment: Does adding -p help?

Comment: -p does make chmod on moved files work. I need to test to make sure it doesn't overwrite permissions on any existing files, though. Thanks. And, I still have the chown issue

Comment: For that you actually need -og I think

Answer (score 39, accepted):

rsync needs to be told that you want to set the permissions and owner/group information. It would be logical to assume that having `--chmod` or `--chown` would tell that but they don't.

For permissions to propagate you need the `--perms` or `-p` flag and for owner/group you need `--owner --group` or `-og` flags for the owner/group/permission information to be set.

The documentation is a bit unclearly written so it isn't clear how the permissions are handled with different combinations or if existing files are affected.

Comment: its still unclear, because running as sudo, which im needing to do, the docs https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync point out that you can only set the destination the same as the source.  The problem is, i need to set it to what the logged user is, e.g. `$(whoami)`

Comment: You also need to check that the current user has permission to perform the `chmod` or `chown` operations (check by running those commands manually).

Answer (score 13):

I found [this StackOverflow version of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177135/rsync-deploy-and-file-directories-permissions?newreg=e99860919e8f4db1b40bb391ff4aa4ab) to be more helpful, because it seems Roger and I have rsyncs with different preferences for the format of `--chmod` (mine is 3.1.3 from a Debian package).

As Sami said, rsync needs to be told "permissions", so either include `-p`, or have it implicitly included by using `-a`. But then, to get the command to actually run, you need (e.g. for directories 755 and files 644) `--chmod=Du=rwx,Dg=rx,Do=rx,Fu=rw,Fg=r,Fo=r`, rather than the "D755,F644" format.

Comment: You also need to check that the current user has permission to perform the chmod or chown operations (check by running those commands manually).